# GLSL - unresolved external on Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, glsl

I'm getting started with the GLSL. What should i do to resolve this:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglLinkProgram
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglAttachShader
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglCompileShader
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglShaderSource
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglCreateShader
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglCreateProgram
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglGetProgramInfoLog
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglGetProgramiv
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pglUseProgram
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using some form of library that wraps GL entrypoints (the entrypoints you list are not direct GL entrypoints).

This library (GLEE ?) likely is coming with a .lib file that you need to link against.

Coming from the [project page of GLEE](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) (my guess, based on a quick googling of who is using the prefix p for GL calls):

> Usage examples
>
> To use GLee, include
>   GLee.h, then simply link to GLee.lib
>   or alternatively add GLee.c to your
>   project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link your program against opengl32.lib, see [here](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/common/howto/winGLUT.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) since OpenGL > 1.5 on Windows is a bit of a pain in the ass. This will get you all OpenGL entry points without messing with extension pointers.